# Angular2 dropdown component scroll into view

Tags: angular

How to scroll into view the selected element of a dropdown box? I got stuck with this issue. With the angular2 pattern bellow I have no reference to the html li tag. The scroll slider should move after the entry field selected and feed with the down arrow key. What should be the best practice? Has anybody any solution, please?

```
    import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
    import { Component, View } from 'angular2/core';
    import { NgFor, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass } from 'angular2/common';

    export class Model {
        constructor(public itemId: number, public value: string, public isFocused: boolean) { }
    }

    @Component({selector: "app"})
    @View({template: `
        <style>
            .drmenu {position: absolute; z-index: 1000; min-width: 250px; background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15); max-height: 60px; overflow-x: hidden;}

            .itemBackground {background-color: red;}
            .selectedItemBackground {background-color: green;}
       </style>

        <div style="position: relative;">
            <input (keydown)="onKeydown($event)"/>
            <ul class="drmenu">
                <li *ngFor="#item of items">
                    <div [ngClass]="{itemBackground: item.isFocused, selectedItemBackground: !item.isFocused}">{{item.value}}</div>            
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        `,
        directives: [NgClass, NgFor]
    })
    class AppComponent {
        items: Array<Model> = [new Model(1, "I1", false), new Model(1, "I2", false), new Model(1, "I3", false), new Model(1, "I4", false), new Model(1, "I5", false), new Model(1, "I6", false)];

        private onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
            var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
            var focusedIndex = this.items.findIndex(i => i.isFocused);
            switch (keyCode) {
                case 38:
                    if (focusedIndex > 0) {
                    this.items[focusedIndex].isFocused = false;
                        this.items[focusedIndex - 1].isFocused = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 40:
                    if (focusedIndex < this.items.length) {
                        if (focusedIndex > -1) { this.items[focusedIndex].isFocused = false; }
                        this.items[focusedIndex + 1].isFocused = true; }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: You can put a `(click)` event into the `<li>` and pass the item itself to the controller so the controller can focus on it. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I can pass it to the controller with the click event but the click event is the item selection itself to close the dropdown box. The issue is the focus at the entry field and while I press the down arrow key the scrolling should invoke in the dropdown box with the active row marker li item. The red active row marker is moving with the key action as I can swap style with ngClass. Had it be a style change event or anything like it would be possible pass the li for the controller. Another approach could be passing the li reference at the instantiation time, but how?

Comment: PrimeNG's dropdown does this automatically for you. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this by implementing a directive and mapping the `<li>` reference with my model:

```
    <li *ngFor="#item of items" [dirItemId]=item.itemId (elementCreated)="elementCreated($event)">
```